# How to fix the error in YAML file converting yaml to JSON? mapping values are not allowed in this context"

Tags: json, kubernetes, yaml

I have been breaking my head trying to understand what the issue is, it shows the following error message:

> error parsing feedback.yaml: error converting YAML to JSON:
>   yaml: line 10: mapping values are not allowed in this context

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
   name: feedback
   labels:
     run: feedback
spec:
   ports:
   – port: 80
     targetPort: 3000
     protocol: TCP
   type: NodePort
   selector:
     run: feedback

---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
   name: feedback
spec:
   replicas: 1
   template:
     metadata:
       labels:
         run: feedback
   spec:
     containers:
     – name: feedback
       image: username/feedback
       ports:
       – containerPort: 8888
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
   name: mongo
   labels:
     run: mongo
spec:
   ports:
   – port: 27017
     targetPort: 27017
     protocol: TCP
   selector:
     run: mongo

---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
   name: mongo
spec:
   template:
     metadata:
       labels:
         run: mongo
     spec:
       containers:
       – name: mongo
         image: mongo
         ports:
         – containerPort: 27017
```

I have checked it using a yaml validator and also checked the spacing, am I missing something?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This was a weird one. Turns out your hyphens were the wrong type :) all your instances of - were actually – (see the difference? one's longer).

Here's a working file:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: feedback
  labels:
    run: feedback
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 3000
      protocol: TCP
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    run: feedback

---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: feedback
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        run: feedback
  spec:
    containers:
      - name: feedback
        image: username/feedback
        ports:
          – containerPort: 8888
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mongo
  labels:
    run: mongo
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 27017
      targetPort: 27017
      protocol: TCP
  selector:
    run: mongo

---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mongo
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        run: mongo
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: mongo
          image: mongo
          ports:
            - containerPort: 27017
```

Side note: this is definitely not node.js – please tag as kubernetes

Comment: Thank you! this is finally working. I see that you have already edited the tag, thanks for that too.

Comment: Glad it worked :) Can you mark as solved if possible? Cheers

Comment: In my case, it was indentation issue. also line number is also wrong. so please check whole file

Comment: @AndyMardell can you explain what the differences are? you never explained the difference.  This is not acceptable `see the difference? one's longer` answer is no cant see the difference, can you explain?

Comment: @uberrebu I'm talking about the literal length of the hyphen, not the file. That's the difference

- vs –

Hopefully that's acceptable ;)

Comment: This can happen when copying and pasting from one editor to another.  Ever notice how in MS word when you type a single hyphen and then space the autocorrect changes it to a slightly different character?  The auto-correct of some editors can cause issues like this.  I saw this same error when I was missing space after the hyphen so it can occur for a variety of other reasons.

Answer (score 0):

I founded a new solution............

1. Copy the code from this website https://github.com/flannel-io/flannel/blob/master/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml.
2. Create a new file **kube-flannel.yml** in you ec2/VM and pass the all code on
   **kube-flannel.yml** file.
3. then try this command:  **kubectl apply -f kube-flannel.yml**

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34832786)